# vacuum not deleting old parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks, delta-lake

We have Azure data lake storing data in parquet files in delta lake format. After every run, where new data is merged, we call vacuum with 0 hour retention to remove old files and run optimize command.

But for some reason, old files are not being deleted. No errors in the databricks notebook though. It says 2 files removed, but i still see them. Am i missing something obvious? Thanks!

```
sqlContext.sql(f"VACUUM  '{adls_location}' RETAIN 0 HOURS")
time.sleep(60)
sqlContext.sql(f"VACUUM  '{adls_location}' RETAIN 0 HOURS")
time.sleep(60)
sqlContext.sql(f"OPTIMIZE '{adls_location}'")
```

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot use `VACUUM` directly on cloud storage. To vacuum storage, you must **mount it to DBFS** and run VACUUM on the mounted directory.

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - Vacuum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/dbio-commit#vacuum-spark)

Comment: I didn't mention it in my question, but in fact, i'm running vacuum on mounted files.

Comment: If you are mounted ADLS storage account, Vacuum command should remove the files as excepted.

Comment: But it is not. Here's the workaround though. Write a separate Databricks notebook to call vaccum command and it works.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can add this an answer and accept ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: `%sql VACUUM` is not working for me (in a separate cell). Files are all there. Table is listed in SHOW TABLES, but can't be accessed by any other commands.